# How to use MediaCodec without MediaExtractor for MP3/AAC sreams

Tags: android, mp3, aac, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

From what I understand, you have to write data to the buffers not as a stream of bytes but as access units.

Right now, I'm reading the data using extractor:

```
int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex], 0);
```

And then this sampleSize is used in

```
codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0 /* offset */, sampleSize, presentationTimeUs, sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);
```

So what are the "access units" for MP3 and AAC ? Are they fixed size chunks ? Can they be somehow read from the MP3/AAC stream ?